# In Battlefield 4, how do I know when I've been issued an order?

Tags: battlefield-4

I've been reading up on Battlefield 4 tactics, and read that orders from commanders and squad leaders are often ignored. I often experience sensory overload while playing Battlefield 4, and can't recall ever seeing an alert to say that I've been issued an order, though I have noticed dotted and solid lines pointing to flags. I want to be a better player, but don't know how this system works. My web searches for screenshots or detailed information have been unsuccessful.

How do I know when a commander or squad leader has issued an order, and how do I acknowledge the order?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say you are playing Conquest. When someone issues an order you will see something like this over the flag identifier:

[image]

It will be an attack order on an enemy flag or objective and a defend on your own flag or objective. So you will see the symbol when you look towards the flag/objective in first person with the identifier (letter) with those marks around it.

Additionally in the mini-map view you can see attack/defend orders that look like this one:

[image]

Objectives are not available in every game mode so you will not see attack or defend objectives in those modes. One for instance is Team Death Match.

Comment: Pending orders from commanders are in BLUE (might only be seen by squad leaders), while the active/squad leader commands are in GREEN. Also commander orders can only be accepted by a squad leader.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Dupree3 said, there will be text in the middle of your screen that says Order Received (though this will disappear).

You can also look at your mini map to see the dotted line.  This shows there is an order pending.  (waiting for you to accept / decline)

*I will provide screenshots of this later today.*

Comment: How do you "accept or decline" an order?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You must be squad leader to accept an order.  For PC - Hold down Q (by default) and the top option will be to accept.  Mouse over it and left click.